# How to throw Network errors in Android WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I am using Android WebView in my App.

I know that there is a method `onReceivedError(final int errorCode, final String description, final String failingUrl)` that gets triggered in `WebViewClient`

I know the WebView triggers it automatically when there is a Network issue such as FILE_NOT_FOUND, CONNECTION_REFUSED etc.

My question is.
Is there an Exception object I can throw which will trigger `onReceiveError()` method?

I need to test different scenarios like "Service is unavailable" etc.